What should my http request be so that I can upload a document via this function?
This is my backend code and I want to send an image file from frontend to this function so it directly uploads to s3 bucket . This code works fine with postman and uploads an image successfully when attached an image to postman.
The problem is that when I try to send an image obj from my react native frontend it gives an error:
const upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        acl: "public-read",
        bucket: BUCKET,
        key: function (req, file, cb) {
           
            console.log("file",file);
            cb(null, file.originalname)
        }
    })
})

app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), async function (req, res, next) {
    // Ensure that req.file is defined
    if (!req.file) {
        return res.status(400).send('No file uploaded.');
    }
    
   
    if (req.file.location) {
        const fileLocation = req.file.location;
        console.log("File location:", fileLocation);
        res.send('Successfully uploaded ' + fileLocation + ' location!');
      } else {
        res.status(500).send('File upload failed. Location property is missing.');
      }

})


This is my frontend code. I tried to create an obj and I have also checked that the obj which I am sending to the backend is the same obj that I printed out when I was sending using postman.
The obj looks similar to this:
{fieldname: 'file', originalname: 'Screenshot (77).png', encoding: '7bit', mimetype: 'image/png', uri: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB4AA…NEAADAAAAAAAANOFw+F965WmOs5jEAAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='}
encoding: "7bit"
fieldname: "file"
mimetype: "image/png"
originalname: "Screenshot (77).png"
uri: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB4A

type hereconst pickSomething = async () => {
    try {
      let result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({});
      console.log("result",result);
      
      const assetsArray1 = result.assets[0];
      
      const file ={
        fieldname: 'file',
        originalname:assetsArray1.name,
        encoding: '7bit',
        mimetype:assetsArray1.mimeType,
        uri: assetsArray1.uri 
      }
      
      console.log("obj file",file);
      
      const formData = new FormData();
      
      formData.append('file',file);
      
      
    }
  
  catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
}


Hi, what error do you get?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
